# How to get django tables2 working on a Cloud 9 django instance

Tags: python, django, cloud9-ide, django-tables2

Can't seem to get django tables2 to work. I am using Cloud 9 dev environment on their cloud service. I installed django tables2 through sudo pip install. I added `'django_tables2'` to the installed apps list. Here is my model:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    project_type = models.ForeignKey(Project_Type)
    created_date = models.DateField()
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
    pm_scope = models.IntegerField()
    dev_scope = models.IntegerField()
    design_scope = models.IntegerField()
    testing_scope = models.IntegerField()
```

Here is my view:

```
def project_list(request):
    table = Project_table(Project.objects.all())

    return render(request, 'person_list.html', {
        'table': table
    })
```

Here is my table class in tables.py:

```
import django_tables2 as tables
from copacity.models import Project

class Project_table(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
```

The error I keep getting is

```
"ImportError: No module named django_tables2copacity.apps"
```

(copacity is my apps name inside the django instance)

I'm new to django so I'm quite lost on this one. Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You are missing the comma after `'django_tables2'` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.